# showGroup not working as expected in R with Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have the following code:

```
# Get unique list of groups needed
lsl <- unique(origAddress$LIHN_Line)

# create initial leaflet
mt <- leaflet() %>%
  setView(lng = sv_lng, lat = sv_lat, zoom = sv_zoom) %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner, group = "Toner") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite")

# for loop to cycle through adding layers
for(i in 1:length(lsl)){
  #l <- lsl[i]
  mt <- mt %>%
    addCircles(
      data = subset(origAddress, origAddress$LIHN_Line == lsl[i])
      , group = lsl[i]
      , radius = 3
      , fillOpacity = 0.6
    )
}

# add layercontrol
mt <- mt %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
    overlayGroups = lsl,
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE
      , position = "bottomright")
  ) %>%
  showGroup("Medical")

# print map
mt
```

The issue is that the `showGroup()` function is not working as I expected. I checked the element of the map and got the following:

```
<span> Medical</span>
```

So I am not understanding why only that group isn't showing.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I will add dummy code tomorrow and str() of data.